# get data from list of lists with linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a model class of Title-Id:

```
public Word
{
   [key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public Guid WordId {get; set;};
   public string WordName {get; set;}
}
```

this words stored in

```
public WordsStorage
{
        public WordsStorage()
        {
            CandWords = new HashSet<Word>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid CandWordsModelID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Word> CandWords { get; set; }
}
```

When I am calling

```
var aaa = db.UserCWords.AsEnumerable().Select(e => e.CandWords ).Distinct(); 
var listOfLists = aaa.ToList();
```

I am getting list of lists of this Words - this is correct.

```
var aaa = db.UserCWords.AsEnumerable().Select(e => e.CandWordsModelID ).Distinct(); 
    var listOfLists = aaa.ToList();
```

for ID - that is working OK too

but If I have a my custom Word

```
Word myCustomWord = new Word();
myCustomWord.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
myCustomWord.WordName = "BadGuy";
```

how to get all CandWordsModelID, in where this word value contained? 
I have tried:

```
db.UserCWords.AsEnumerable().Where(e=>e.CandWords.Where(s=>s.WordName.Contains(myCustomWord.WordName))).Select(e => e.CandWordsModelID).Distinct()
```

but get an error `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<prj.Models.Word>' to 'bool'`

Comment: @Luiso, you didn't provide any link for a question

Comment: So you want to get a list of lists, but you want to filter the internal lists? Why are you using `Distinct`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: sorry this is the link to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494807/linq-query-list-within-another-list

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var myWord = ...
db.UserCWords
    .Where(e => e.CandWords.Any(w => w.WordName.Contains(myWord.WordName)))
    .Select(e => e.Id)
```

there is no need for calling `Distinct` since no word store is processed twice.
The issue with you code seems to be that you are trying to filter using the result of a `Where` which returns a `IEnumerable<T>`. Now if you take a look at the signature of the `Where` method you'll see that it takes a `IEnumerable<T>` and a predicate (`Func<T, bool>`) and it returns a `IEnumerable<T>` so when you call the outer `Where` it expects a predicate and since you are using another `Where` inside you are giving it a `Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>` instead of a `Func<T, bool>`. You need to use `Any` to achieve what you are doing

Answer (score 2):

Change this expression:

```
e => e.CandWords.Where( s => s.WordName.Contains( myCustomWord.WordName ) )
```

to use `Any` instead of `Where`:

```
e => e.CandWords.Any( s => s.WordName.Contains( myCustomWord.WordName ) )
```

`Where` will filter `CandWords` for matching entities where `Any` will return a boolean of any of the entities in `CandWords` matches your criteria, which I believe is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because you basically have Where( ... Where(...) ...)  The outer Where expects a Boolean expression, but the inner Where() returns an IEnumerable.

Try changing the inner Where() to use Any().  Any() will return true if it's able to find an object in the collection that satisfies the criteria.

I'd be curious why you need to call AsEnumerable() on db.UserCWords.  If UserCWords is IQueryable you would want to call Where and Select before calling AsEnumerable, ToList, etc.  Otherwise you're pulling the entire collection from the database and evaluating the LINQ expression on the client (instead of having the LINQ expresion be converted to SQL.)